# What would cause https to load over wifi, but not over mobile data?

Tags: ssl, mobile, https, lets-encrypt

We're having problems with https loading over mobile data.

Everything works fine over wi-fi.  And non-ssl http works fine over mobile.

We've tested on android as well as ios, using at&t and cricket networks.
Currently using lets-encrypt for the ssl certificate.

Domain is oletymeshop.com

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *"We're having problems with https loading over mobile data."* - please describe the problems you are having in as much detail as possible, i.e. the exact error messages you get or a specific behavior you see (timeout, broken html, malfunction of script ....) in detail.

Comment: I should have been more clear.
Error is connection timeout
Centos 7, Bind DNS, Apache webserver with php.

Page being served is a wordpress site, but tried a plain html page as well.  Same result.

No activity at all in the access_log when it tries.  It seems like it's just hitting a wall.  

My first thought was firewall, but I don't know why it would effect only mobile networks.  Disabling the firewall makes no difference.

Comment: Also, it is effecting all domains on the server.

Comment: I've seen a similar post referring to incorrect ipv6 addresses, but ipv6 is disabled.